# access php array elemen in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have this in php:

```html
'position' => [
   'label' => ['Pic Position', ''],
   'inputType' => 'select',
   #'default' => 'left',
   'options' => [
    'left' => 'Left',
    'right' => 'Right',
   ],
  ]
```

now i want if 'Left' is selected, that a class called left is added to a div! I cannot figure out the php syntax for that!

```css
<div class="floating_text" <?php if ($this->position == 'left') echo 'class="left"' ?>>
  <?= $this->text ?>
 </div>
```

this is clearly wrong!

Comment: what is exactly "position" ? A PHP array ?

Comment: Print out `$this->position` and see if it holds `left` or `right`. Also, don't add two `class=...`, add it to the already existing `class` attribute. Also remember that PHP is serverside so if you want to change that value via a `<select>` you'd first need to submit the changes or use Javascript to attach that class onChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your PHP condition into the existing `class=` instead of trying to create another instance of `class=` which is wrong.

```
<div class="floating_text <?php echo ($this->position == 'left') ? 'left' : '' ?>">
        <?= $this->text ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@kerbholz thanks for the tip!

```html
<div class="floating_text <?php if ($this->position === 'left') echo left ?>">
```

or I could have also just done this:

```html
 <div class="floating_text <?php echo $this->position ?>">
```